# Where is the best place to put code that handles UI transitions and manipulations?

Tags: objective-c, ios, model-view-controller, user-interface

I have the following piece of code in my MainViewController.  Is that the best place for it?  I have several other methods which have similar behavior.  Does this type of code belong in a separate class just for UI transitions and manipulations?

```
-(void)slideView3P{
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:_view3P];
    if (view3PIsMinimized){
        view3PIsMinimized = NO;
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"animationOff" context:NULL]; 
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5f];
        [_view3P setFrame:CGRectMake(_view3P.frame.origin.x, 7, _view3P.frame.size.width, 446)];
        [UIView commitAnimations];    
    }
    else {
        view3PIsMinimized = YES;
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"animationOff" context:NULL]; 
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5f];
        [_view3P setFrame:CGRectMake(_view3P.frame.origin.x, 57, _view3P.frame.size.width, 46)];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me, I will create a model called Helper and create class methods for animation like the followings:

```
+ (void)slideHoriWithPixel:(CGFloat) _pixel ForView:(UIView *) _view;

+ (void)slideVertWithPixel:(CGFloat) _pixel ForView:(UIView *) _view;

+ (void)popOutAnimationForView:(UIView *) _view;
```

There will be some simple and complex animations.

The benefits are:

- You will never know when you will reuse these animation.
- Even when you do another project, you can simply import this Helper Model back to the new project
- After you have done serval projects, this model may finally become your own animation library.

Comment: Do you just do a class that is subclassed from NSObject?

Answer (score 1):

In my applications, I usually place my transitions in the view controllers, like you are currently doing. However, if you want to reuse the transitions, you could place them in a separate class and import it into the various view controllers in which you desire the transitions. Just a note: I would not use `beginAnimations:context:` and `commitAnimations`, as Apple does not recommend them. Taken from the [UIView Class Reference:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html)

> **Animating Views**
>
> Use of the methods in this section is discouraged in iOS 4 and later. Use the block-based animation methods instead.
>
> +beginAnimations:context:
>
> +commitAnimations
>
> +setAnimationStartDate:
>
> +setAnimationsEnabled:
>
> +setAnimationDelegate:
>
> +setAnimationWillStartSelector:
>
> +setAnimationDidStopSelector:
>
> +setAnimationDuration:
>
> +setAnimationDelay:
>
> etc...

Hope this helps!